# Filter input from keyboard in Textbox, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0, c#-4.0

I want to filter the keyboard inputs into textbox based on the type of input I allow. e.g.

0 for Digits only
1 for Alphabets only
2 for Alphanumerics

So if 0 is configured and a character 'a' is pressed on the keyboard, it is not shown in the textbox. How do I do that in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to control's KeyPress event (and optionally KeyDown method), and if key stroke must be eaten set **Handled** property to true. Read more in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) (with sample that cover your problem).

Comment: I chose this answer because it gave me a general approach to handle this kind of an issue. Other good answers are equally good and can be used depending on the case.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I understood your question correctly but you can use [masked text box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) for creating many types of input filters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expressions. according to the user input you get, you can change your regular expression/validation method.
below is an article that explains how to extend a textbox to validate against regular expressions. hope that helps at least to have some idea.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/RegExTextBox01022007150131PM/RegExTextBox.aspx