# How to make a textbox only accep a-z and nothing else?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, masking

I have 4 text boxes at a Windows form. I would like to change it to only accept letters the letters a to z and nothing else, even when content is pasted in. If the user pastes in a mix of letters and unwanted characters, only the letters should show up in the textbox.

The last thing that I would like to have is the numlock pad. Those numbers are the same as the number row at a top of a keyboard, but I want to them to block them too!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036870/filter-input-from-keyboard-in-textbox-c-sharp

Comment: You only can filter data going into textbox when inputting from keyboard.  You can't stop somebody from pasting data into the textbox.

Comment: You can use a `MaskedTextBox` and set the [`Mask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) property to a suitable mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suppose to introduce a custom control derived from `TextBox`, by analogy with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374050/2858407):

```
public class LettersTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        string c = e.KeyChar.ToString();

        if (e.KeyChar >= 'a' && e.KeyChar <= 'z' || char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            return;

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        {
            string text = Clipboard.GetText();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return;

            if (text.Any(c => c < 'a' || c > 'z'))
            {
                if (text.Any(c => c >= 'a' || c <= 'z'))
                    SelectedText = new string(text.Where(c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z').ToArray());
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: The name 'SelectedText' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: @Donovan that's strange. It's a property of WinForms' TextBox.

Comment: Idk, This is what VS says.

Comment: @Donovan did you inherited exactly `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`? It should have this property - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Uhm.. where should I add this?

Comment: @Donovan add this class into your project, build it and then you should be able to add this control from the designer toolbar on your form.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this: I have to add a new class to this project, (right clikck project, add -> class. Name it and then add the line System.Windows.Forms.TextBox and paste the other code part under?

Comment: @Donovan Yes. My code misses namespaces - this is usual. You should prepend it with all necessary `using` statements. I've asked about TextBox since it can be confused with classes from other libraries, e.g. ASP.Net. You need Windows.Forms here.

Comment: @Donovan remove `class Letterbox`. `LettersTextBox` class should be standalone, not nested. And it should be inherited from  `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`, not Letterbox.

Comment: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point when I want to run it

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there should be some syntax that looks like; 
`var isAlpha = char.IsLetter('text');`
All you need to do is implement the syntax to your textbox, as shown;
`var isAlpha = textbox.char.IsLetter('text');`

Comment: I am a novice, but I have used that before and it worked.

Comment: That could but the issue is not about detecting the content of the  string but removing the unwanted characters.

Answer (score 0):

In the ASCII table a-z is form 97 to 122:

```
string str = "a string with some CAP letters and 123numbers";
void Start(){
    string result = KeepaToz(str);
    Debug.Log(result); // print "astringwithsomelettersandnumbers"
}
string KeepaToz(string input){
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(char c in str){
       if(c >= 97 && c<= 122){ sb.Append(c); }
   }
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I realize that I assumed it was for Unity...but the method should work just the same for any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TextChanged` event. Something like:

```
// Set which characters you allow here
private bool IsCharAllowed(char c)
{
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
}    

private bool _parsingText = false;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if we changed the text from within this event, don't do anything
    if(_parsingText) return;

    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if(textBox == null) return;

    // if the string contains any not allowed characters
    if(textBox.Text.Any(x => !IsCharAllowed(x))
    {        
      // make sure we don't reenter this when changing the textbox's text
      _parsingText = true;
      // create a new string with only the allowed chars
      textBox.Text = new string(textBox.Text.Where(IsCharAllowed).ToArray());         
      _parsingText = false;
    }
}
```

You can assign this method to each of the textboxes `TextChanged` events, and they will only allow them to enter what is in `IsCharAllowed()` (doesn't matter if via pasting, via typing, touchscreen or whatever)